# How to keep leading zero when incrementing string

Tags: java

I need to generate a sequence as follows:

PAY000000 - The first three characters(PAY) remain the same and the 000000 should be incremented by one:

I have tried the following method to generate a sequence number:

```
   public String generateSequence(String currentPayment) {

        String chunkNumeric = currentPayment.substring(3, 9);
        return "PAY" + (Integer.parseInt(chunkNumeric) + 1);

    }
```

Expected:

```
currentPayment: PAY000000  Expected value: PAY000001
currentPayment: PAY000001  Expected value: PAY000002
```

Actual Result:

```
currentPayment: PAY000001  Actual value: PAY2
```

The issue is when I pass PAY000001 as parameter the `Integer.parseInt(chunkNumeric)` remove all the leading zeros that is PAY2 generated instead of PAY000002.

Any idea how I can increment the string while keeping the leading zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should instead maintain the sequence as a *number*, i.e. an integer or long, and then *format* that number with left padded zeroes:

```java
public String generateSequence(int paymentSeq) {
    return "PAY" + String.format("%06d", paymentSeq);
}

int seq = 1;
String nextSeq = generateSequence(seq);
```

Comment: I wonder if `return String.format("PAY%06d", paymentSeq);` would make any difference to your solution. May depend on how frequently this method is used.

Comment: @deHaar Your version doesn't make much sense (at least to me).  No need in converting from string to int, then back to string again.

Comment: Yes, that's nonsense, I corrected the comment already ;-) Was the code OP posted. The only difference I am thinking about is the inclusion of `"PAY"` into the `String` passed to `String.format`